# What affects the level of available missions?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

When you begin a new save file, all the missions that can be selected are green (level 1) and short. Gradually, I've noticed more and more medium and long missions as well as yellow (level 3) missions.

What triggers these missions showing up? The possibilities I can think of are:

- Average level of your heroes
- Highest level of your heroes
- Number of weeks passed
- Number of heirlooms collected
- Number of missions completed
- Number of bosses defeated

Finally, is there a point where level 1 missions no longer appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available mission types are short, medium, and long, yes, and the levels available are currently 1, 3, and 5.

My understanding is the rate of longer and harder missions showing up is merely by weeks completed, I don't have a reference for this though.

Short and level 1 missions never totally go away, I was still getting two to three (four?) level one missions, and the occasional short mission at week 102.